# Como faço login num repositorio?

Tags: git, terminal, bitbucket

Precisei alterar a senha no bitbucket, então o `push` e o `pull` do meu repositório local não funcionam mais. Eu me autenticava via *https*.

Qual comando usar para me autenticar no repositório e inserir o username e password?

Comment: Não, o título não diz tudo. Qual o URL de conexão usado? Você passa o seu usuário ou usa um _umbrella_ que depois identifica com a chave ssh? O repositório está como _http_ ou _https_? Qual a mensagem de erro? Tem certeza de que não é problema com o _head_  estar desatualizado? Verificou que você tem acesso à leitura e escrita do tal repositório?

Comment: A questão aqui é que a password foi alterada e agora nao consigo fazer pull nem push. No entanto não sei como autenticar-me de novo.

Comment: A autenticação é ssh ou http ou https? Continua não informando

Comment: A autenticação é Https

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado obrigado pela edição.

Comment: As informações a respeito do seu remoto ficam no arquivo de configuração do git (`.git/config`). Não recomendo editar diretamente, mas pode lhe dar uma guia. Achei isso aqui que parece ser relevante: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5343068/4438007. Entretanto, recomendo bastante trocar a autenticação _https_ a favor da _ssh_, mas reconheço que é mais mania minha do que algo objetivo. Para trocar para _ssh_, primeiro é adequado subir a sua chave pública para o bitbucket. Se usa Windows, recomendo não usar o `putty`, mas sim o `openssh` (a integração com o `putty` não é suave, já  `openssh` é)

Comment: Talvez também seja relevante: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35942754/4438007

Comment: algum erro é apresentado?
vc está usando git ou hg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você utilizava *https* com seu repositório sem fornecer o usuário e senha a cada `pull`/`push`, provavelmente suas credenciais (usuário e senha) estavam salvas usando o `credential.helper` do próprio Git.

Para alterar elas, você tem que chamar os comandos:

```
git config credential.helper store
git pull
```

Após isto, o Git vai perguntar para você qual o usuário e senha. Forneça o usuário e a nova senha e faça novamente o teste de acesso em seu repositório.